# Capturing and handling the 'click' event of 'bigplaybutton' of videojs is not working

Tags: javascript, video, html5-video, dom-events, video.js

I'm using videojs from https://vjs.zencdn.net/5.16.0/video.min.js to embed a video in my page. I have an action to be performed on click of the 'bigplaybutton'.

[image]

I tried to get the element by class name vjs-big-play-button(i haven't created a button explicitly...just using the one from videojs) and add an event listener to it.

```
document.getElementsByClassName("vjs-big-play-button").addEventListener('click', somefunction);
```

(or)

```
document.getElementsByClassName("vjs-big-play-button").onclick = function(){
    console.log("play");
};
```

Neither of them work. I'm not sure if my approach is right. Kindly suggest a solution to achieve this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So I made further research and found a solution which works. But still not sure why  getting the element by class name din't work. So here is the solution which worked for me.

```
var player = videojs("videoElementId");
player.bigPlayButton.on('click', function(){
    // do the action
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add event on Big Play Button you can use the bellow code :

```
 var previewPlayer = videojs(document.querySelector('.video-js-preview'));

  previewPlayer.bigPlayButton.on('click', function () {
               // your action here.
            });
```

if you want to add event on video play you can use the below:

```
previewPlayer.on('play', () => {  // your action here. });
```

Comment: player.on('play', ()=> {console.log('play~')})

Answer (score 0):

getElementsByClassName will return array of elements by class name. So if you have only one, then it can be called document.getElementsByClassName("vjs-big-play-button")[0]