# video.js Handle Click Event of the play/stop Button

Tags: javascript, video.js

Hey Guys similar to the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52931795/capturing-and-handling-the-click-event-of-bigplaybutton-of-videojs-is-not-wo) I would like to execute custom JavaScript, but when the small play/stop Button of video.js is pressed.
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P2wVg.png) Until now I was not able to find a way of doing that, any Ideas?
Thanks

Comment: How is the button created? You can listen click handler and play video? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add an event listener on the button component.

```js
player.controlBar.playToggle.on('click', function() {
  console.log('click');
});
```

Comment: Is there a way to ensure that the first play also gets triggered? Your solution works but not on the first play. Is there a workaround other than using first-play event?